# js passing a variable to a function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass a variable created with dynamic content to a function inside Javascript. The only problem is in the console it returns undefined, but its undefined with the value being passed

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: zukeru is not defined profile.html:1 onclick
```

Code:

```
function getFriend(friend){
  console.log(friend,toString());
  document.cookie = "getuser="+friend;
  window.location="profile.html";  // change url to your's
}


function getFriendlist(){
    var profile_pic_friend = '';
    var flist = Cynergi.get('http://:3000/friends?my_username=eq.' + get_user);
    var flist_html = 'Friends: ';
    $.each(flist, function(i, item) {

        var profile_pic_ret = Cynergi.get('http://:3000/profile_pictures?username=eq.' + item.friend_username );
      $.each(profile_pic_ret, function(i, item) {
        profile_pic_friend = item.pic_location;
      });

        flist_html = flist_html + "<div><a onclick='getFriend("+item.friend_username+");'><img width='100' height='100' src='"+ profile_pic_friend + "'><br>" + item.friend_username + "</a></div>"
    });
    $("#flist").html(flist_html);
    setTimeout(function() { getFriendlist(); }, 1000);
}
getFriendlist();
```

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(item.friend_username)` instead of just `item.friend_username` in the html attrib

Comment: And where is `zukeru` in the posted code ?

Comment: @adeneo yes its the value that is being sent to the function thats what im not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is failing is because `item.friend_username` is a string, so when you generate the link like this:

```
flist_html = flist_html + "<div><a onclick='getFriend("+item.friend_username+");'><img width='100' height='100' src='"+ profile_pic_friend + "'><br>" + item.friend_username + "</a></div>"
```

**You are missing quotes to specify that it is a string**. As you are not wrapping the value with quotes, the browser understand that what you are passing is a variable (in your case `zukeru`) and it fails because it is not defined.

To solve the problem, wrap the variable value with quotes (you'll need to escape them for this particular case), and the problem will be fixed:

```
flist_html = flist_html + "<div><a onclick='getFriend(\""+item.friend_username+"\");'><img width='100' height='100' src='"+ profile_pic_friend + "'><br>" + item.friend_username + "</a></div>"
```